# Linux, search for image files

Tags: linux

I found that I have about 200.000 of png files in my computer during Places>Search for files>*.png. But in this list they are represent as name/path and gray square.
Is here any program in synaptic (or other method) that I can search and see image files on my computer as visible pictures?

Comment: -1 is too localised, what OS you are using ? are you using GUI?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome desktop.

Comment: Can you include the above information into your question? Also, comment is for someone like me (who like to complain) to make some noise, it usually does not help with your question.

Comment: Try `pornview`, which is a fine image viewer for Linux (available through your packet manager). I think it comes with thumbnailing features, as well as a convenient browsing interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose view type as "Icon View", or use "ctrl+1" which is the hotkey for this type of view.

Comment: In Places>Search for files there is no other view! If you mean from nautilus? But from nautilus I cannot search for all such files on disk. Or I can?

Comment: Places>Search for files> IS nautilus and yes - you can specify any location, ergo you can specify /

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about synaptic, but from a command line or terminal you can use the "find" command to locate files.

You could use this command line:

```
find $HOME -iname \*.png -type f -print
```

This starts in your home directory and recursively finds anything matching the filespec (which has a backslash to avoid misinterpretation by the shell you're typing the command into). The `-type f` is a condition to insure that you will only match actual files, not directories or devices. The final `-print` just prints the filename but you could terminate with a command like `-ls` if you wish.

Note that a Linux desktop may have MANY png files that are installed as part of your desktop environment (i.e. Gnome) and software packages.  To find things outside your home directory, replace `$HOME` with some other starting point in the command line above (or `/` to search for absolutely everything).  To get a complete view, you may have to run the command as root.